# Can someone elaborate the following sentence for me, specially the bold part?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, philosophy

Reactions to German Idealism, especially those of the neo-Kantians, logical positivists and Bertrand Russell, were also instrumental in the founding of analytic philosophy, **which today reveals and benefits from an increasingly sophisticated appreciation of the European philosophical tradition.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for a philosophy board, which can better appreciate the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the phrase into two parts as follows:

*Analytic philosophy reveals an appreciation of the European philosophical tradition.*

and

*Analytic philosophy benefits from an appreciation of the European philosophical tradition.*

Does that help?